unable to get consistent layout with tailwind for relative container
I am trying to build a form layout in a NextJS project with tailwind CSS.
here is the CodeSandbox Link for the issue.

After running the code in sandbox, please click the button the view the resulting webpage in full page
Issue 1: when the form is unfilled, we can see the input:file element in proper way as intended.

but as soon as we add a file which has a long name, the size of the element gets distorted, ideally it should clip the extra part, though it is able to clip but somehow the long text is causing it distort

<!--Main Section Containing all elements-->
<section>
            <h3 className="m-0 text-2xl font-medium">Upload Policy Doc</h3>
            <div className="flex flex-col gap-8 py-8 px-0 border-0 border-solid border-b border-charcoal-200">
              <div className="flex gap-10">
                <div className="flex flex-col w-1/3 gap-1">
                  <h5 className="m-0 text-rg font-normal">Allowed Duration</h5>
                  <h6 className="m-0 text-sm font-normal text-gray-400">
                    Ut enim ad minim veniam.
                  </h6>
                  <h6 className="m-0 text-sm font-normal text-gray-400">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
                  </h6>
                </div>
                <div className="flex items-start w-2/3 gap-4">
                  <KWInputText className="w-1/2" />
                  <KWSelect
                    id="leave_format_sick"
                    name="leave_format_sick"
                    data={[
                      { label: "Days", value: "day" },
                      { label: "Weeks", value: "week" },
                    ]}
                    className="w-1/2"
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="flex gap-10">
                <div className="flex flex-col w-1/3 gap-1">
                  <h5 className="m-0 text-rg font-normal">
                    Credit leaves monthly
                  </h5>
                  <h6 className="m-0 text-sm font-normal text-gray-400">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
                  </h6>
                </div>
                <KWInputRadio
                  className="flex items-start w-2/3 gap-4"
                  name="is_sick_leave_credited_monthly"
                  options={[
                    { label: "Yes", value: "true" },
                    { label: "No", value: "false" },
                  ]}
                />
              </div>
              <div className="flex gap-10">
                <div className="flex flex-col w-1/3 gap-1">
                  <h5 className="m-0 text-rg font-normal">
                    Another Size Check
                  </h5>
                  <h6 className="m-0 text-sm font-normal text-gray-400">
                    Ut enim ad minim veniam.
                  </h6>
                  <h6 className="m-0 text-sm font-normal text-gray-400">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
                  </h6>
                </div>
                <div className="flex items-start w-2/3 gap-4">
                  <KWInputText className="w-1/2" />
                  <KWInputText className="w-1/2" />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="flex gap-10">
                <div className="flex flex-col w-1/3 gap-1">
                  <h5 className="m-0 text-rg font-normal">
                    Upload your leave policy document
                  </h5>
                  <h6 className="m-0 text-sm font-normal text-gray-400">
                    Your employees will be able to download this policy document
                  </h6>
                </div>
                <KWInputFile
                  name="leavePolicyDoc"
                  id="leavePolicyDoc"
                  accept="application/pdf"
                  className="flex items-start w-2/3"
                />
              </div>
            </div>
          </section>

<!--Select Element Component-->

const KWSelect = ({
  id,
  name,
  data,
  className = "",
}) => {
  return (
    <div className={className}>
      <div className="relative w-full h-full">
        <select
          id={id}
          name={name}
          className="block w-full h-full appearance-none border border-solid border-charcoal-300 py-[10px] pl-5 pr-8 rounded-xl text-rg font-normal"
          
        >
          {data.map((optionSet, index) => {
            const ids = `${name}-opt${index}`;
            return (
              <option
                key={`key-${ids}`}
                value={optionSet.value}
                label={optionSet.label}
              >
                {optionSet.label}
              </option>
            );
          })}
        </select>
        <div className="pointer-events-none absolute inset-y-0 right-0 flex items-center px-2 text-charcoal-300">
          <CaretDown weight="fill" size={24} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default KWSelect;


<!--InputFile Element Component-->

const KWInputFile = ({
  accept,
  id,
  name,
  className = "",
  customFileName = "",
  folderPath = "leaves",
}) => {
  const [uploadStatus, setUploadStatus] = useState("idle"); // 'idle', 'uploading', 'uploaded', 'error'
  const [selectedFile, setSelectedFile] = useState<File | null>(null);
  const fileInputRef = useRef(null);

  const handleFileChange = async (event) => {
    return new Promise((resolve)=>{
        const file = event.target.files[0];
        if (file) {
        setSelectedFile(file);
        setUploadStatus("uploading");
        try {
            setTimeout(() => {
                setUploadStatus("uploaded");
                resolve();
            }, 1500);
        } catch (error) {
            // console.error("Upload failed", error);
            setUploadStatus("error");
        }
        }
    })
    
  };

  const handleCancelUpload = () => {
    setSelectedFile(null);
    setUploadStatus("idle");
    if (fileInputRef.current) {
      fileInputRef.current.value = "";
    }
    // Add any additional cancellation logic if needed
  };

  return (
    <div className={className}>
      <div className={`relative flex w-full`}>
        <input
          type="file"
          name={name}
          id={id}
          className="opacity-0 absolute cursor-pointer h-full w-full"
          accept={accept}
          onChange={handleFileChange}
          ref={fileInputRef}
        />
        <div className="flex w-full items-center justify-between border border-solid border-charcoal-300 rounded-xl py-[10px] px-3">
          <span
            className="flex-grow text-charcoal-500 font-normal text-rg overflow-hidden whitespace-nowrap text-ellipsis"
            // style={{ maxWidth: "calc(100% - 40px)" }}
          >
            {selectedFile ? selectedFile.name : "Choose file"}
          </span>
          {uploadStatus === "idle" && <UploadSimple size={24} />}
          {uploadStatus === "uploading" && (
            <SpinnerGap size={24} className="animate-spin" />
          )}
          {uploadStatus === "uploaded" && (
            <XCircle
              size={24}
              onClick={handleCancelUpload}
              className="cursor-pointer z-10"
            />
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
  );
};

export default KWInputFile;

Issue2: the layout is using w-1/2 for dividing two elements in a row in half. as seen in case of 2 input tags and 2 radio buttons, if we check the size of the element through chrome devtools we can see it's divided in perfect halves and both the elements have same width,

but for the row with  tag and  tag the widths are not equal and the input tag takes little extra space than the select tag.
I am new in tailwindCSS and CSS concepts, please help me fix this..

Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself  preferably in a Stack Snippet using the <> icon.. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link.


Your element is shrunk, add shrink-0 to it and it won't be shrunk. 2. You should consider gap when specifying the width of flex child elements, if your child elements are w-1/3 + w-2/3 with gap it is going to overflow if you don't allow flex-shrink. 3. And you seem to want strict alignment, in which case using grid is more reliable than flex.


hi @Paulie_D , i have already reproduced the issue and provided it in a codesandbox. will update the question for few code snippets

will try out your suggestions @KarsonJo
